# Elastica and Json Field

Tags: json, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

I am looking for a way to map a string field of one table of a sql db to json with elastica. This field (valueFloat) contains a json representation of a large table with numerical value. The idea would be to be able to search for a specific value within this json array. I'm trying to do this mapping with the yml config of elastica.

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    app:
        types:
            ...
            tableContent:
                properties:
                    argument1Name:
                        type: string
                    valueFloat:
                        type: string
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: TAMAS\AstroBundle\Entity\tableContent
            ...
```

I am considering using a pipeline with the json processor but fail to do so... Also it might not be the most straightforward method

Any advice ?

Comment: The JSON processor is one good way to handle such a case. Can you explain what you have try to configure your ingest pipeline ?

Comment: Hey! thanks for your message; neither the "pipeline" key nore none its child in the documentation is accepted in the yml conf... I just realize I wasn't on the most recent version so I will try the JSON processor again.

Comment: I succeeded to create a working pipeline and I can transform my data by *reindexing* it by curl request. However I can't find a way to use this pipeline directly at the first *indexation* at the level of the mapping config .yml. There seems to be no way to define a mapping which automatically use pipeline. Any idea ?